# Tensorflow, keras with RTX3080 in windows 10 not working

Tags: windows, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am using anaconda python 3.8 virtual environment with PyCharm IDE.  I have installed cudnn and cudatoolkit using( `conda install -c conda-forge cudnn`). I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMmCu3Nm1xA&t=45s)  but `tf-nighlty-gpu` gives me keras error so I have install tensorflow==2.2.1 and keras==2.3.1 into virtual environment using pip. The problem is that I always get this error (please check the picture attached) and it takes ages to run the example [code](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu).

```
import tensorflow as tf

try:
  with tf.device('device:XLA_GPU:0'):
    a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
    b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
    c = tf.linalg.matmul(a, b)
    print(c)
except RuntimeError as e:
  print(e)
```

I have also attached the picture to show the installed libraries and their versions using `conda list` if this would help you in understanding the problem. Thanks in advance for the help!!

[image: when I run the example code]

[image: list of libraries installed with their versions]

Comment: The version of Tensorflow you have doesn't have built-in binary support for your GPU, so it is relying on driver run in time recompilation before it can run anything. That is why it is extremely slow

Comment: @talonmies Thank you for your comment. What TensorFlow and Keras version would you suggest me?

Comment: There is no error message in the picture you attached, only unrelated information and warnings. What is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yes there is no error but it takes more time than CPU for computation.

Comment: @talonmies No, you are wrong, the GPU is being used, that is clear from the log.

Comment: Of course it uses more time, you are making a tiny multiplication that does not require a GPU to be computed fast.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Even if I use any convolutional network for the prediction with Keras it still takes more time comparatively.

Comment: GPUs are only faster than CPUs for big models due to data transfer and execution latency to the GPU, if your model is small then you will not see an improvement, this does NOT mean that the GPU is not working, it is a common misconception. There is no issue here.

Comment: My model has 11Million parameters with 26 conv layers. and it takes 30 seconds for prediction for a single 960x600 image. I was quite able to do with GPU for inference with less than a second. But somehow with new tf-nightly-gpu it is not working that is why I put this question.

Comment: I would not use nightly versions are they are untested, if there is a regression then you should open an issue in TensorFlow with full details (which are not in this question), not ask a question here. And please note the contradictions in your question, a question should be a clear issue which is not the case here.